# Unexpected token in angular2 when importing AgGridModule

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm trying to add ag-grid to my Angular2 code, when I add AgGridModule to the @NgModule imports, I causes the following error: (SystemJS) Unexpected token at eval

```
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpModule, routing, Ng2Bs3ModalModule, AgGridModule],
```

When I remove AgGridModule from the imports list, it runs without a problem.
Any ideas?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you find the solution?


_(I am using Angular4 and latest ag-grid-angular@13.1.0)_

Comment: I rebuilt the entire project from scratch, adding the ag-grid early in the game. The error did not recur.

Answer (score 0):

With Angular 4.3.4, I have to do this :

In systemjs.config.js :

```
System.config({
paths: {
  "npm:": "node_modules/"
},
map: {
  (...)
  "ag-grid": "npm:ag-grid",
  "ag-grid-angular": "npm:ag-grid-angular"
},
packages: {
  (...)
  "ag-grid": {
    main: "./main.js", defaultExtension: "js"
  },
  "ag-grid-angular": {
    main: "./main.js", defaultExtension: "js"
      }
    }
  });
```

In [file].module.ts :

```
import { AgGridModule } from "ag-grid-angular";
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AgGridModule.withComponents([]), (...)
```